# После отправки сообщения на стороне одного клиента, другой клиент не получает его.

Tags: python, многопоточность, сокет, chat

У меня есть такой сервер

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import fnmatch
import _thread

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
## Allow socket to be reused by application - doesn't force timeout.
serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9000
serverSocket.bind((host, port))

connectedUsers = []

serverSocket.listen(5)


def threadedClient(clientStream):
    while True:
            clientMessage = clientStream.recv(1024).decode()
            print(clientMessage)
            if "Username:" in clientMessage:
                    username = clientMessage.replace("Username:","")
                    print(str(username) + " has connected!")
                    connectedUsers.append(clientAddress)
                    print(str(username) + "" + str(clientAddress) + " has connected to server")
                    for users in connectedUsers:
                            print(users)
                            clientStream.sendto(str.encode(username) + " has connected!".encode(), users)
            if "Text:" in clientMessage:
                    receievedText = clientMessage.replace("Text:","")
                    for users in connectedUsers:
                            clientStream.sendto(receievedText.encode(), users)
                            print("Sending message " + str(receievedText) +" to:" + str(users))
            if not clientMessage:
                    break

while True:
    clientStream, clientAddress = serverSocket.accept()
    _thread.start_new_thread(threadedClient,(clientStream,))
```

Есть такой клиент

```
import socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9000

username = input("Please enter username: ")

clientSocket.connect((host, port))
clientSocket.send("Username:".encode() + username.encode())

def receiveServerMessage():
    serverMessage = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(serverMessage + '\n')


while True:
    receiveServerMessage()
    command = input(username + " > ")
    if command != None:
        clientSocket.send("Text:".encode() + str.encode(command))
    if command == str("q"):
        exit()
clientSocket.close()
```

После отправки сообщения на стороне одного клиента, другой клиент не получает его. Собщение отправляется только самому себе, хотя на сервере видно, что сообщение было отправлено обоим клиентам.
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему.

Comment: попробуйте Ctrl-C нажать на клиенте, чтобы увидеть где он висит. Вероятно просто код блокирован на input() вызове.

Comment: Ctrl-C не дает ничего, оно просто выделяет всю строку

Comment: это вы внутри какого-то IDE запускаете? В консоли Ctrl-C должен KeyboardInterrupt исключение в вашем коде вызвать.

Comment: да я работаю в PyCharm, можно тогда подсказать какой комбинация клавишь там нужно

Comment: как в PyCharm показать traceback для выполняемого кода, вы можете как отдельный вопрос задать. (Ctrl+C я упомянул как быстрый способ увидеть, где код блокирован -- это никак к текущему вопросу не относится). Для правильной работы, ваш код обязан *одновременно* читать ввод от пользователя и от сервера